# Report processing error in ssrs2005 query

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

In the past Month I have been trying all different ways to tackle this problem. I am trying to pull data back where an Audit was done yesterday at all branches but has an Audit which was done 30 days ago at branch HO but I'm not sure why it takes a long time to calculate and then errors saying 
Report processing has been canceled by the user.

The query I have is

```
SELECT  Audit.oventype, Audit.Date, Audit.Branch, Damage.DamageDesc, Damage.ActionDesc

FROM  Audit AS Audit LEFT OUTER JOIN Damage AS Damage ON Audit.ID = Damage.AuditID

WHERE (Audit.Date BETWEEN @Datefrom AND @DateTo) AND
          (Audit.Branch IN (@Branch)) AND 
          (Audit.oventype IN
          (SELECT     oventype
           FROM          Audit AS Audit_1
           WHERE      (Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, - 30, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(second, - 1, GETDATE())) AND (Branch = 'HO')))
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to write the query 
Any ideas or help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: When you run this query directly against the database, does it finish successfully?

Comment: sometimes it errors and sometimes it does finish and display the results

Comment: You may want to try and make variables for the date range between the Audit table. It will calculate the DateAdd functions every time. Declaring them as variables will only perform the function once.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean